# Require.js in MVC app

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs

Something wrong and I can't figure it out.

`_Layout.cshtml` has:

```
 <body>
      <script data-main="Scripts/main" 
          src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/require.js")" 
          type="text/javascript">
      </script>

      @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

/Scripts/main.js:

```
require.config({
   paths: {
       "jquery": "jquery-1.9.1"
   }
});
```

All the way down on index.cshtml:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery'], function ($) {

        });
    </script>
}
```

and it throws 404 trying to find jquery.js. What am I doing wrong?

upd: yes main.js gets called and if comment everything in index.cshtml and put to the end of main.js it something like

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
   $(function(){
      alert('jquery loaded');
   })
});
```

it shows the message

Comment: First of all, why are you rendering scripts?  Let requireJs take care of that.  Second, have you debugged into main.js to see if is getting called?

Comment: Stupid question: jquery.js is in the right place, yes?

Comment: yes @DavidL main's been called. I want to have `code-behind`.js for each view. so on each view scripts section should require a module

Comment: @Agzam That is one way to do it.  However, is this a traditional full view app or a partial/SPA app?  If each controller returns a completely new view, I can understand your design decision.  If not, I'd recommend using RequireJS to handle what module gets loaded and when

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up by removing `data-main` attribute from `_Layout.cshtml` and calling main directly from the page:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(['Scripts/main'], function () {
            require([ "views/home-index"] );
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It just occurred to me what your issue is.  You're using Paths where you should be using a map.

Try the following, it'll map your jquery file to a short name for you.

```
require.config({
   baseUrl: '/scripts',
   map: {
       "jquery": "jquery-1.9.1.js"
   }
});
```

In addition, there's a good chance if you hit index it isn't loading your requirejs file in time.  If you declared it in your index first, I think that would prevent a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

[@David L is correct.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533654/require-js-in-mvc-app#comment22005866_15533654)

When the javascript inside of the scripts block in index.cshtml runs, your `require.config` block likely hasn't run yet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should place the script section in head tag in _Layout.cshtml, the reference of main.js is usually in head, so the config is called before, I guess that's the reason.